# How can I create a sub-timer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a periodic timer in my Flutter app, which changes some values on a page every x seconds:

```
periodicTimer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: timer), (Timer t) {
            setState(() {
              if (globals.selectedBottomNav == 0) {
                nextKey();
              } else {
                nextCircleKey();
              }
            });
          });
```

However, I need to be able to perform another action in a shorter time. So, for example, if my timer variable is set to 5 seconds, I need to be able to run my setState every 5 seconds, but after 3 seconds of each timed loop, I want to run some other code.

Any help on how I could achieve that? I've tried with various nested Timer and Timer.periodic options, but get strange results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set on having this done using a single timer, how about just shortening that timers duration and count the seconds yourself

```
int secondsCounter = 0;
periodicTimer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
  secondsCounter++;
  
  if(secondsCounter == 3){
    // do stuff that's supposed to happen after 3 seconds
  } else if(secondsCounter == 5){
    // do stuff that's supposed to happen after 5 seconds
  }
  
  if(secondsCounter >= 5){
    secondsCounter = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I wanted

Comment: It would seem to me that a generalization of this approach should already exist, and if it doesn't exist already it would be useful. It would take a list of tasks to run, each with an associated period and phase that were multiples of the short timer tick. Sort of like cron...  There is a package called Work Manager https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager that allows background scheduling as an independent task on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with this simple implementation. If you are having unexpected behavior with this, please update your question with a detailed explanation of expected vs actual behavior, as well as any other solutions you have tried.

```
periodicTimer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: timer), (Timer t) {
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    // perform other operations here
  });

  setState(() {
    if (globals.selectedBottomNav == 0) {
      nextKey();
    } else {
      nextCircleKey();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try something similar but was getting strange results with the second timer executing after I had stopped the process. Most probably my coding :-) Alex's solution has solved my problem.